# Inequality about 'sum of square' and 'sum of absolute'

Tags: inequality

Suppose Phytagoras's theorem $$ a^2 = b^2 + c^2   \to  \vert a \vert < \vert b \vert + \vert c \vert $$
It is true.
But I wonder following  :  $ a_i , b_i  $ is non-zero real, and natural numbers n, N (edit)
$$     n<N $$ 
$$ \sum _{i=1} ^n a_i ^2  = \sum_{i=1 }^N b_i^2  \to  \sum _{i=1} ^n \vert a_i \vert < \sum_{i=1 } ^N  \vert b_i \vert   $$
Is it true ?

Comment: No it isn't true. You could just take $a_i=b_i$ for $i=1,\dotsc, n$ and then $b_i=0$ for $i>n$.

Comment: Ah,, when $ b_i =0 $ isn't true !! How about  when $ b_i $ is non-zero ?

Comment: Even if you enforce $b_i > 0$ it is still false.

Comment: Thanks Koymans,, Is there some counter-example?

Comment: You can twist the above counterexamples by adding "a tiny bit" to each zero $b_i's$. For instance, $33^2 + 33^2 + 33^2 = 3267 = 57^2 + 1^2 + \cdots + 1^2$ (18 1's).

Comment: Or smallest example when $n = 2$, $N = 3$: $10^2 + 7^2 = 12^2 + 2^2 + 1^2$.

Comment: Oh,,Thank you Hw Chu ,,, I see that I have a stupid idea !!

Answer (score 1):

Set $a_1 = \cdots = a_n = 1$ and $b_1 = \sqrt{n}$, $b_2 = \cdots = b_N = 0$, then for $n > 1$ there is $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n a_k^2 = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^N b_k^2$ but $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n |a_k| > \sum\limits_{k = 1}^N |b_k|$.

Comment: sorry .. I will edit some conditions.. that ' $a_i , b_i $ is non- zero real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy the newer requirement of strictly positive numbers, set $a_1=\dotsb=a_n=1$ and $b_1=\sqrt{n-1}$, $b_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ for $i>1$, and take $N=n+1 > n$, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 = n = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}b_i^2$$
whereas
$$\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i| = n,\quad \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}|b_i| = \sqrt{n-1} + (n)\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{n-1} + \sqrt{n} < 2\sqrt{n}$$

Given that $n-2\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n}-2\right)\geq 0$, if $\sqrt{n}\geq 2$, then $n \geq 2\sqrt{n}$ for any $n\geq 4$, it follows that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i| \geq 2\sqrt{n} > \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}|b_i|,\quad\text{for $n\geq 4$}$$

Comment: Thank you.. I see my fault..